# Synchronizing each database of a central mongoDB server with a database on a different host

Tags: mongodb, synchronization

My application stores events in a mongoDB database that is saved locally on the client pc (amongst others databases used for others purposes).
I'd like to write an analytics dashboard displaying stats computed from the events databases (consolidating data obtained from all clients).
First step is to upload data from the clients pc to my central mongoDB server.

After browsing the docs, I reached following conclusions :

- analytic server can be part of a replica set as a SECONDARY slave member with *priority=0* as I'm just interested to duplicate data to perform reads, the PRIMARY master being the database on client pc.
- I would need to scale this slave/master replication as many times as there is clients so that on my analytics server we have as much databases as client, each database being synchronized with a different server.

Starting multiple instances of `mongod` seems bad practice.
I want to achieve the analytics server being SECONDARY to multiple PRIMARY servers (each SECONDARY/PRIMARY pair having a dedicated database), is that even possible ?
Should I perform the sync with different clients without relying on the *replica set* concept ?

**Update:**
so I'd be better using `mongoimport/mongoexport` ?
From http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/import-export/#data-import-and-export-and-backups-operations

> By contrast, use import and export tools to backup a small subset of your data or to move data to or from a 3rd party system. These backups may capture a small crucial set of data or a frequently modified section of data, for extra insurance, or for ease of access.

Comment: Nope, that's not possible. All members of a replica set strive to store the same data. Also, there can be only one primary. I think it makes sense for all clients and the analytics server to operate on the same central database, that's much easier and it's unlikely you will overload the database in a locally connected scenario.